# MBEDTLS_ERR_CTR_DRBG_ENTROPY_SOURCE_FAILED

Tags: c, random, diffie-hellman, mbed, mbedtls

im trying to code a Diffie-Hellman key Exchange (client side) into a XMC4500 and I'm using [ARMmbed lib](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls).

This is the code I got (based on [dh_client.c](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/programs/pkey/dh_client.c)):

int dhm (void)
{

```
int ret;
size_t n, buflen;

unsigned char *p, *end;
unsigned char buf[512];
unsigned char hash[32];
const char *pers = "dh_client";

mbedtls_entropy_context entropy;
mbedtls_ctr_drbg_context ctr_drbg;
mbedtls_rsa_context rsa;
mbedtls_dhm_context dhm;
mbedtls_aes_context aes;

mbedtls_rsa_init( &rsa, MBEDTLS_RSA_PKCS_V15, MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256 );
mbedtls_dhm_init( &dhm );
mbedtls_aes_init( &aes );
mbedtls_ctr_drbg_init( &ctr_drbg );

/*
 * 1. Setup the RNG
 */

mbedtls_entropy_init( &entropy );
ret = mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed( &ctr_drbg,
                            mbedtls_entropy_func,
                            &entropy,
                            (const unsigned char *) pers,
                            strlen( pers ) );

mbedtls_aes_free( &aes );
mbedtls_rsa_free( &rsa );
mbedtls_dhm_free( &dhm );
mbedtls_ctr_drbg_free( &ctr_drbg );
mbedtls_entropy_free( &entropy );

return ret;}
```

I did not try to go further this, because it is not working and it is the very beginning of dhm algorithm. The function **mbedtls_ctr_drbg_seed** is returning **MBEDTLS_ERR_CTR_DRBG_ENTROPY_SOURCE_FAILED**.

Also in the [ctr_drbg.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/include/mbedtls/ctr_drbg.h) I had to edit the **MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_MAX_SEED_INPUT** from 384(default) to 336, otherwise the code would crash. Everything else is default.

Someone knows why is returning this error?
Thanks in advance.

Note: Im calling this function in main. Running the code gives me no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned when your entropy function(`mbedtls_entropy_func`) fails. Do you have an entropy source enabled? You probably don't have any strong entropy source configured in your platform, thus causing this failure.